# Work out which address ruby on rails app is listening on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thin, puma

I would like to work out from within my app whether the app was started with plain old `rails s` or with `rails s -b 0.0.0.0`, i.e whether the server is listening to `tcp://localhost:3000` or `tcp://0.0.0.0:3000`. How do I do this?

Comment: Do you have any specific context?

Comment: I guess this boils down to the question: "Where do I get the current `Rails::Server` instance" ...

Comment: In response to Rich Peck's question, the context is that I only use ```rails s -b 0.0.0.0``` when I access the development server from a device such as an iphone on the local area net. When I do this, I have to change the address of the assets from ```config.asset_host = 'localhost:3000'``` to specify the ip address of the local server. I would like to make this switch automatically.